# How do i customize ajax alrt to modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I dont understand some of the tutorial so i came here for the help.

the problem is i want to customize confirm alert to a modal

here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) // this is the message that i want to customize into a modal
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"delete",
                method:"POST",
                data:{user_id:user_id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

here is the function in url:delete

```
if(isset($_POST["user_id"]))
{
    $statement = $connection->prepare(
        "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id"
    );
    $result = $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':id'   =>  $_POST["user_id"]
        )
    );

    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo 'Data Deleted';
    }
}
```

and here is the code of modal that i want to use

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-confirm="Realy?|Do you want to continue?" data-confirm-yes="alert('Deleted');">Delete</button>
```

Comment: "the code of modal that i want to use" ... so, why don't you use it?  What exactly is the problem that you're having?  Are you using some framework like jQueryUI or Bootstrap?

Comment: @PatrickQ i dont know how to use ajax and how to implement the html code into it

Comment: How do you not know how to use ajax?  You're using it already in your first block of code up there.

Comment: I just copied the code